# WSO2 ESB Uploading Artifacts

Tags: deployment, wso2, esb, uploading, wso2-esb

I create custom mediator by DS (v 3.2.0) and upload JAR in according to article
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Uploading+Artifacts (WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-4.8.0 )
But I get exception 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Class bisB.TestReqB not found in the path
even after reload ESB.
Can I do hot deployment of mediator at all?

(if I put JAR to \repository\components\dropins, after restart ESB, I have no errors.)

manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: bisB;uses:="org.apache.axiom.soap,org.apache.synapse,o
 rg.apache.synapse.core,org.apache.axiom.om,org.apache.synapse.mediato
 rs"  
Built-By: germ  
Tool: Bnd-1.15.0  
Bundle-Name: TestReqB  
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin      
DynamicImport-Package: *  
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25  
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0  
Bnd-LastModified: 1387867159131  
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2  
Bundle-Description: TestReqB  
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestReqB  
Import-Package: org.apache.axiom.om;version="[1.2,2)",org.apache.axiom
 .soap;version="[1.2,2)",org.apache.synapse,org.apache.synapse.core,or
 g.apache.synapse.mediators
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Places+for+Putting+Custom+Mediators

```
In all these cases you have to restart the server after putting the mediator.
```